# MyTask getting unwantedly executed when building

Tags: gradle

I want to print a link to our team's documentation if the developer types:

```
gradle help
```

using this task:

```
task help {
        println "Full Documentation"
        println "https://confluence.org.com/Help"
}
```

which it does.

However, I do not want it to execute when I run:

```
gradle build
```

Is the help task supposed to run whenever build is run? If not, why does this task get executed? As you can tell, my understanding of gradle is limited.

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively overriding the built-in `help` task that Gradle provides. As a result, other tasks or plugins in your project may be referencing that task already or other parts in the overall Gradle build rely or use `help` in some fashion.

To summarize, do not override Gradle built-in tasks otherwise it will lead to unexpected/unintended consequences.

To fix, rename your task to something other than `help`.

Comment: ok that helps thank you.But why would the default help task get invoked every time I run a build (even when the build succeeds)? That is counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: In fact, even if the task is called `help2` it still gets printed when running `gradle help`. Is there a way to make a task only get executed if explicitly mentioned? It seems to automatically get hooked into the configuration phase.